# How to pass multiple parameters to the express js server api in a mean.js application?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, mean-stack, meanjs

The default serverside router for a mean.js application for a single parameter request is like this :

```
app.route('/articles/:articleId')
        .get(articles.read)
        .put(users.requiresLogin, articles.hasAuthorization, articles.update)
        .delete(users.requiresLogin, articles.hasAuthorization, articles.delete);

    // Finish by binding the article middleware
    app.param('articleId', articles.articleByID);
```

How do I parse multiple parameters in the middleware for the request say :

```
app.route('/articles/:articleId/:lineId')
```

How do I define the middleware for this ?

I have tried doing :

```
app.param(['articleId','pageId'],articles.articleByID);
```

but it fails. Even the express.js API says that an array of arguments can be passed but it's vague on it's implementation.

I even tried accessing req.param in the middleware definition but it returned undefined.

Somebody please guide as to how to implement it?

Comment: Try `req.params` in middleware

Comment: [Using Express middlewares](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html)